# How to disable color blend

Tags: html, css

I created two rectangular shapes with two `span` with a grey background. But when the two shapes intersect, the colour is darker on the parts that are overlapped. How do I "disable" this so I have a consistent color?

```
 .rectangle1
  position: absolute
  right: 22px
  bottom: 0px
  height: 80px
  width: 12px
  background-color: grey

 .rectangle2
  position: absolute
  right: 22px
  bottom: 30px
  height: 45px
  width: 6px
  background-color: grey
```

Comment: are you sure the color is darker? there is no opacity in your code ..

Comment: You must have something else going on - this is not how css works unless you specify opacity - here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/hr5a2kcz/3/

Comment: Please try to produce a minimal example and post it in its entirety. The two CSS code fragments in the question *do not* produce the stated effect by themselves.